# Save image as session and display it

Tags: php, html, image

I'm trying to save a file/image as session and then display it..

here's the first page which contains the form:

```
  <form method="post">
   <input type="file" name="picture" value="upload" id="file" accept="image/*" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
           </form>
```

Ok, so on then next I save the image as session and try to show it (which is unsuccessful)...

Code:

```
        <?php 
      if (isset( $_POST['picture'])) 

        $_SESSION['picture'] = $_POST['picture'];

        echo  "<img src=" $_SESSION['picture'] " border='0' /> " 
          ?>
```

Comment: Start reading here ~ http://php.net/manual/features.file-upload.php

Comment: As phil stated above ^ and also, you need `session_start()` if you even want to think about storing session variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what you will actually do but this is the approach that best fits

when you put a file type in your form, you need to use the global variable [$ _FILES](http://php.net/manual/fr/features.file-upload.php)

**form.html**

```
 <form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="picture">Picture:</label>
  <input type="file" name="picture" id="picture"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //make sure you have created the **upload** directory

    $filename    = $_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"];
    $destination = "upload/" . $_FILES["picture"]["name"]; 
    move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination); //save uploaded picture in your directory

    $_SESSION['picture'] = $destination;

    header('Location: display_picture.php');
```

**display_picture.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<div>
  <img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['picture']; ?>" alt="picture"/>
</div>
```